Elastic Search 7.10 - date formatter error
We have migrated to 7.10 Version of Elastic Search from 6.18.  We are using Spring data Elastic Search library in our spring boot application. We see a lot of datetime conversion error, some of them we fixed. But the below one we are unable to identify for which entity and for which attribute it is being thrown . Any help would be appreciated since debugging is taking a lot of time with some many entities .Not sure if it not getting a Date formatter format or some data null error.
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimePrintContext.<init>(DateTimePrintContext.java:119)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.formatTo(DateTimeFormatter.java:1846)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.format(DateTimeFormatter.java:1822)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.ElasticsearchDateConverter$PatternDateFormatter.format(ElasticsearchDateConverter.java:261)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.ElasticsearchDateConverter.format(ElasticsearchDateConverter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.mapping.SimpleElasticsearchPersistentProperty$1.write(SimpleElasticsearchPersistentProperty.java:227)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.propertyConverterWrite(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:693)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.writeProperties(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:657)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.writeInternal(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:633)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.writeProperty(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:742)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.writeProperties(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:674)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.writeInternal(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:633)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.writeInternal(MappingElasticsearchConverter.java:611)
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.convert.MappingElasticsearchConverter.writeCollectionInternal(MappingElasticsearchConverter


The mapping file has some formats specified .
